# How can I change the color of the top most bar (Carrier/Clock etc.) in iOS using Forge?

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I am trying to customize the color of the top most bar in an iOS app using Trigger/Forge. Is that even possible? I couldn't seem to find anything about it in the docs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's called status bar and it has 3 possible styles: opaque gray, opaque black and translucent black (50% opacity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** we're re-considering implementing status bar customisation. The reasons:

- Android doesn't support styling of the status bar (you can only show/hide)
- the status bar is not style-able at all on the iPad (see [The Status Bar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html))
- on Windows Phone the system tray appears and hides according to activity

Until we can find some good common ground that will be useful and applicable cross-platform, we're putting this on hold.

Original answer:

This is not currently possible with Trigger.io: you're the first requester :)

I've created a story to address this and will report back here when it's complete. Estimated completion: 4th June 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary solution for hiding it(however it might work for styling also)
If you want do hide it you can still edit the Info.plist file in the result of your build(you will have to do it every time you completely re-build you app)

EDIT:

I just checked it and yes you can change the status bar style by adding the  : 
Status bar style key to Info.plist file

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to completely remove the status bar with the fullscreen option in our display module:

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/display.html#field-fullscreen

We have not implemented status bar customization per James' answer